# Mistake in reasoning about Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

I am new to Sobolev spaces and, while trying to construct a proof, I make some subtle mistake that I cannot detect.

The setting: let $C \subset \Bbb R^n$ be a closed, measure-$0$ set. Let $U = \Bbb R ^n \setminus C$. Let $f : \Bbb R ^n \to \Bbb C$ be continuous, $f$ smooth of infinite order on $U$ but *not* derivable on $C$, and $f \in L^p (\Bbb R^n)$.

1) Clearly, $f \in W ^{\infty, p} (U) \ \forall p \ge 1$.

2) By defining $f_\alpha (x) = \left\{ \begin{array} {cc} (\partial _\alpha f) (x), & x \in U \\ 0, & x \in C \end{array} \right.$ for every multi-index $\alpha$, $f_\alpha$ is a weak derivative of $f$ on $\Bbb R^n$, so $f \in W^{\infty, p} (\Bbb R^n)$. Note that this seems to have nothing to do with Sobolev's extension theorem.

3) Localize: choose a small enough ball $B_x$ around every $x$. The restriction $f \big| _{B_x}$ will belong to $W ^{\infty, p} (B_x)$.

4) By Sobolev's embedding theorem, $f \big| _{B_x}$ will be smooth of infinite order on $B_x$.

5) Glueing these restrictions together, $f$ will be smooth of infinite order on $\Bbb R^n$, in particular on $C$, where is was supposed not to be so.

Where am I wrong? (There may be several mistakes above, not just one.)

(The motivation behind my question: replace $\Bbb R^n$ by a Riemannian manifold $M$, fix some $p \in M$ and let $f = d(p, \cdot)^2$ ($d$ the distance) and let $C$ be the cut locus of $p$.)

Comment: Part 1) is also not clear. For $f \in W^{\infty, p}(U)$ you would need that all derivatives $\partial^\alpha f$ lie in $L^p (U)$. In general this does not have to be the case, even though $f$ is smooth with $f \in L^p$.

Comment: @PhoemueX: True, but for reasons not explained above this worries me less, I think that I can achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you deduce that $f \in W^{\infty,p}(\mathbb R^n)$ in step (2)?

As a simple illustration, take a function $f$ that satisfies $f(x) = |x|$ on a neighborhood of the origin, is $C^\infty$ away from $0$, and has compact support. Let $C = \{0\}$.

Then $f \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb R)$, $f$ is infinitely differentiable in $U = \mathbb R \setminus C$, but the weak derivatives of higher order don't extend across $C$ :  $f \notin W^{2,p}(\mathbf R)$.

Comment: Are you using $f$ for both the function and its smooth truncation, or am I misreading you?

Comment: Yeah, let me reword that.

Comment: I think I've got it, by simplifying your example: take $f : (-1,1) \to \Bbb R$, given by $f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array} {cc} -1, & x<0 \\ 0, & x=0 \\ 1, & x>0 \end{array} \right.$. For a test function $\phi$ with $\text{supp} \ \phi = [0, r)$ with ($0<r<1$) one has $\int f \phi ' = -2 \phi (0)$, giving that $f$ is the Dirac $\delta$ concentrated in $0$, which is not even an integrable function, let alone a weakly derivable one. So, $f \in W^{\infty, p} ((-1,0) \cup (0,1))$ but $f \notin L^p (-1,1)$ for any $p$.

Comment: Aren't you assuming that $f$ is continuous? If you take $f(x) = |x|$ you have (a.e.) the formula for $f'$ which is clearly not in $W^1$.

Comment: Also, in your example $f$ **is** in $L^p$, just not $W^{1,p}$.

Comment: In my example given a few minutes ago, I was concentrating on what you would call $f'$. I only wanted to reduce your argument to its core and remove the surrounding clutter, in order for me to understand it better. I don't deny what you have written.

Answer (score 0):

In the same sense as Umberto's asnwer: $f\in W^{p,\infty}(U)$ does not yield any information near points in $C$. The reason is that the weak derivative is defined with smooth test functions in $C_c^\infty(U)$. These are zero in a neighborhood of  $C$!

Hence the localization argument fails: $f|_{B_x}$ is in $W^{p,\infty}(U \cap B_x)=W^{p,\infty}(B_x\setminus C)$
but not in $W^{p,\infty}(B_x)$ in general.

Comment: I see. If I choose $\phi \in C^\infty _0 (\Bbb R^n)$ a test function with compact support, then you say that the second "$=$" in the following is wrong? $$\int \limits _{\Bbb R^n} f \ \partial _\alpha \phi = \int \limits _U f \ \partial _\alpha \phi = (-1)^{|\alpha|} \int \limits _U \partial _\alpha f \ \phi = (-1)^{|\alpha|} \int \limits _U f_\alpha \phi = (-1)^{|\alpha|} \int \limits _{\Bbb R^n} f_\alpha \phi$$

Comment: The second "=" requires $\phi$ to be compactly supported in $U$. You don't have that.